# Get all search text from given search input

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am getting below search text as input `ABC XYZ "ABC1 XYZ1" 123 456`
here spaces are delimeter, but if search text is there in double quote with word containing space then whole word in double quote will be consider as whole search text. so here i need to search for below item

```
1. ABC
2. XYZ
3. ABC1 XYZ1
4. 123
5. 456
```

could anyone suggest any regular expression logic or split logic to get the above result for search option.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: What have you tried? Please share. Maybe `Regex.Matches(input, """(?<val>[^""]*)""|(?<val>\w+)")` will be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the values by using named capturing groups and two alternative regex that matches substrings inside double quotation marks, or non-delimited words:

```
Dim input As String = "ABC XYZ ""ABC1 XYZ1"" 123 456"
Dim vals As List(Of String) = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(input, """(?<val>[^""]*)""|(?<val>\w+)").Cast(Of Match)().Select(Function(m) m.Groups("val").Value).ToList()
```

Output:

[image]

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%22(%3F%3Cval%3E%5B%5E%22%5D*)%22%7C(%3F%3Cval%3E%5Cw%2B)&i=ABC%20XYZ%20%22ABC1%20XYZ1%22%20123%20456)

The `(?<val>[^""]*)""` part matches `"something here"`-like substrings, and `(?<val>\w+)` matches `word_134`-like  substrings. All are captured into a named group "val" (.NET regex supports multipile group name declaration, the last captured value is kept in it).

**UPDATE**

You may use `\S` shorthand class to match *any* non-whitespace symbol:

```
"(?<val>[^"]*)"|(?<val>\S+)
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%22(%3F%3Cval%3E%5B%5E%22%5D*)%22%7C(%3F%3Cval%3E%5CS%2B)&i=ABC%20XYZ%20%22ABC1%20XYZ1%22%20123%20456%204.5%20%256655%26])

Comment: @stribizhev- for input like `4.5`. regular expression is returning as 
1. 4
2. 5
but it should consider it as 4.5 as single search string.

Comment: Since you supplied example strings without clear requirements, I suggested the simplest solution that looked generic. If you plan to match all non-whitespace symbols (again, I do not know the requirements, I assume that), use [`"(?<val>[^"]*)"|(?<val>\S+)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%22(%3f%3cval%3e%5b%5e%22%5d*)%22%7c(%3f%3cval%3e%5cS%2b)&i=ABC+XYZ+%22ABC1+XYZ1%22+123+456+4.5+%256655%26).